# Set Custom Duration for MKMapKitView Animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, mkmapview

I'd like to slowly pan on a MKMapkitView worldmap from left to right. At most MapKit map movement functions you can set a boolean value for turning animation on or off but you cannot set the duration as far as I can see. E.g.

```
[worldmap setCenterCoordinate:av.annotation.coordinate animated:YES];
```

How can I slow this down and set a custom duration for this kind of animation of a map movement?

Comment: in ios5 this worked with an animation block and centerCoordinate; in higher versions than ios5 this dos not work anymore. One should file a bug to apple. Did you found a solution in the meantime?